# Best practices for hacking in tuples into Prisma

Tags: postgresql, prisma

I have a postgres database where for one of the tables it is important to track who has seen what and when. For example:
Alice looks at Bobs post today and Mallory looks at it tomorrow.
Here I would want a column for my posts table where I store Alice's user id and todays date as one entry and Mallory's user id and tomorrows date as another entry.

In psql this is trivial, I just query my database with

```
CREATE TYPE foo AS (
    id INT
    date DATE
)
```

but there doesn't seem to be support for this in Prisma.

My solution then is to hack it in and I am wondering about the best way to do this as I'm still learning. I think I only really have three options: another table, using json or the raw type but I don't fully understand what that is so it might not even be relevant.

EDIT: For anyone who comes across this later. I ended up adding another table which had the two fields.

Comment: "in psql this is trivial, [...] but there doesn't seem to be support for this in postgres" - could you clarify this thing? I'm certain Postgres supports `CREATE TYPE`, and don't quite get the difference between Postgres and `psql` in this context...

Comment: That is a simple brainfart, i have editet the question now but I ment to say prisma